# Finding out what is using time stamps (privacy manifest required by Apple)

Tags: ios, manifest, privacy

I just got the email from Apple saying my app is using functions that require a privacy manifest to justify their use. The two that are required are NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults and NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp.  But I don't want to add the privacy manifest without knowing what is calling these forbidden functions. I can add it for the user defaults (really Apple? Who doesn't use defaults??) but I can't find anything in my apps using time stamps. When I go to Apple's website it says the functions that flag this are **creationDate**, **modificationDate**,
**fileModificationDate**, **contentModificationDateKey**, **creationDateKey**, **getattrlist**, **getattrlistbulk**, **fgetattrlist**, **stat**, **fstat**, **fstatat**, **lstat**, and **getattrlistat**. None of which are in the link map that I generated by following the instructions from Quinn The Eskimo.

I don't use 3rd-party compiled libraries other than ones provided by Apple, but those methods should still show up in the link map, yes? So I'm really puzzled by what is calling any of these methods.

The only clue I'm getting is that my app uses a class called refStation and when I search in the link map for **fstat** it finds a method that returns the refStation. But it can't be that simple, can it? Apple can't be just using a blind text search and flagging anything it finds? At least, I hope not!

Is there another way find out what in the app might be calling any of these functions, other than the link map - which does not show them in it?

Comment: They aren't "forbidden functions", they are just functions. Either declare `C617.1` or perhaps `3B52.1' if you use a document picker view controller and move on.

Comment: I want to know why, so I put a breakpoint on fstat and lo and behold it stops about a dozen times before calling main(). I don't know what it's looking at, but something is calling into that. The break point is for something called Security :: UnixPlusPlus :: FileDesc :: fstat(stat&) const ID 2.2.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is on iPadOS. A similar app on iOS doesn't link in with fstat, according to the link map. I'm trying to see if there is some setting that forces file security on iPadOS but so far I can't find anything out of the ordinary. But I'm still looking.